# Custom UIDragPreview's position relative to drag touch

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uidragpreview

I am trying to provide a custom **UIDragPreview** when user drags an item from my UICollectionView. It works but shifts the preview down resulting in user holding the dragged preview from the top. Default behaviour is to hold the preview from the point user initiated the drag from. Is there a way I can reset the position of the preview OR offset its position relative to the touch. Below is gist of my code:

```
extension UIDragItem {
    func preview(size: CGSize) -> UIDragPreview? {
        var dragPreview: UIDragPreview?
        let expansion: CGFloat = 1.1
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: size.width * expansion,
            height: size.height * expansion
        ))
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: self.localObject as? UIImage)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: size.width * expansion,
            height: size.height * expansion
        )
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        dragPreview = UIDragPreview(view: view)
        return dragPreview
    }
}
```

which I am calling from:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, dropSessionDidEnter session: UIDropSession) 
{
    if collectionView.hasActiveDrag {            
        for dragItem in session.items {
            dragItem.previewProvider = { () -> UIDragPreview? in
                return dragItem.preview(size: <SendingCollectionViewCellSizeHere>) 
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing the same issue.